# ASP .Net MVC application not working on IIS (Social external login application)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I did facebook and google authentication in asp .net mvc its working fine in debug mode but whenever i publish my site to local IIS, its not working showing error "this site can be reached".

Please help

Comment: To make this question answerable, show your IIS site settings and also tell what URL gives you that error.

Comment: URL is localhost/MySite

Comment: Probably you should get started from site bindings, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you must set your URL in authorized redirect Urls in  google api `Credentials`
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-configure-google-sign-in-for-Asp-Net-mvc-5-part-sixt/